# end of month Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, activesupport

My Ruby app is showing the beginning of the month (day 1) when processing:

```
start_month => Date.today.month
```

I would like the end of the month, so I changed it to:

```
start_month => Date.today.end_of_month
```

but it is showing the beginning of the month. Would you know why?

Based on the comments, I rewrote as follows, yet it still does not work. I am sure I am misspelling something

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :delivered_at, "Estimated delivery"  %><br />
  <%= f.date_select(:delivered_at.end_of_month, :start_year => Date.today.year, :start_month => Date.today.end_of_month,:prompt => { :month => 'Choose month', :year => 'Choose year'}, :discard_day => true) %>
</div>
```

Comment: `Date.today.month` does not show the beginning of the month, it shows the month. And, there is no `Date#end_of_month` in plain Ruby with `require "date"`.

Comment: If you're using Rails, then `end_of_month` should indeed show the end of the month (for example invoking this today would give you `Sat, 30 Nov 2013`). There should be no errors or unusual behaviour. There is most likely something else wrong in the code, or some part that we're not seeing.

Comment: @Teeg +1, most likely some other problem. If you want to do this outside of rails/activesupport, Date.new(2013, 11, -1) will give you the last day of the given year/month.

Comment: actually I just wrote end_month => Date.today.end_of_month and it is still not working

Comment: @Mel Are you using Rails or is this a plain 'ol Ruby app? Try Eric Andres' suggestion.

Comment: @Teeg, it is Rails.Date.today.end_of_month works just find in the Rails  console but when I edit the file and make the change it is not working

Comment: @Mel What happens if you do it in a `binding.pry` session at the same point and type in `Date.today.end_of_month` manually?

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: @Lukas, Yep, I restarted the server.

Comment: @Mel That doesn't make much sense. You will probably need to show the entire file, whichever one contains this line. And Dave Newton's suggestion is good too; install the [`pry` gem](https://github.com/pry/pry) and set a breakpoint in the file like he pointed out. That way you can perform the command within the context of this "file" and should be able to examine the environment to determine why it's messing up.

Comment: @Dave, it is manually working

Comment: Hi guys, I just edited the question above with 2 files where the code appears pls have a look

Comment: @Mel If it works manually then something else is stomping on the value, if you're actually setting the correct value originally. Callbacks?

Comment: @EricAndres you mean that if I write Date.month.new it will show the end of the month?

Comment: No, that doesn't work. Date.today.month is just an integer. If you want to get the last day of the current month you would do `Date.new(Date.today.year, Date.today.month, -1)`.

Comment: alright, thanks guys. I need to go through the files again and check what can cause the code not to work. I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Given the code for the views you've shown, I'm guessing your problem is in your controller code. If you look at the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select) for `f.date_select`, discarding the day causes it to default to the first day of the month. Unless you're doing something with `delivered_at` in your controller, it's always going to be the first day of the month, so you need to change it to `delivered_at.end_of_month` before saving the model.

Comment: I have edited my question below, as it still not working. I am sure I am mispelling smth

Comment: If you can, post your controller code. That will give a lot more information that your view code does.

Answer (score 0):

```
Date.today.to_date.end_of_month
```

output :

```
Sat, 30 Nov 2013
```

AND

```
Date.today.to_date.end_of_month.month
```

output:

```
11
```